# Android service or thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-service

Hi in android I need send requests to a server every 30 seconds while the app is running without interfering with the user. Would it be advisable to do this in a service or thread, or a service with a new thread?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).Use AlarmManager to call the service.In service write the code for send request to server

Answer (score 0):

**Service:** A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user

While `thread` is a concurrent unit of execution.You can use both for your purpose and another option is `Runnable` with `Handler` where you can call operation or code for every 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) (as Chaitu said) as well as [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a Service rather than creating one thread. The Android developer site states the following:

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is
>   going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such
>   as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to
>   do that work. More information on this can be found in Processes and
>   Threads. The IntentService class is available as a standard
>   implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules
>   its work to be done.

Since the Service runs in the UI thread you should create a new thread in the service that makes request every 30 seconds to the server.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to write an **[IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)** not a simple Service and inside it write a static method to send a request to server with backoff time 30 seconds and in your activity just start the service.

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer - "Should you use a service or a thread?"

A service is simply a component that can run in the background even when the user is not interacting with your application. Thus, you should create a service only if that is what you need.

If you need to perform work outside your main thread, but only while the user is interacting with your application, then you should probably instead create a new thread and not a service.

Remember that if you do use a service, it still runs in your application's main thread by default, so you should still create a new thread within the service if it performs intensive or blocking operations.